# Is there a way to set the rowHeight in react-grid-layout library such that all the content in cells appear?

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using react-grid-layout library to create a board with draggable cards. The content of the cards are not static. Based on the settings input from the user, some components are added to the cards. In each card, there is a title, maximum three lines of summary and maximum 1 line of description as you can see in the image. When the summary is shorter than expected, the content except the title does not appear at all on the card.

[image: Cards]

I tried to change rowHeight property to make the rows bigger, but although it enlarges the cells with full content, it did not work on the ones with less lines of summary. I also tried to give min-height to my summary element, but then cards started to overlap. What can I do to make all content appear on the cards?
This is where I create GridLayout:
`

```
<GridLayout
  className="layout"
  style={{
    backgroundColor: colors.N20,
  }}
  layout={newLayout}
  width={cols * 300 + (cols - 1) * 10}
  cols={cols}
  isResizable={false}
  rowHeight={MAX_SUMMARY_LINES < 3 ? 65 : 30}
  onDragStop={(_, __, item) => someFunc(item)}
>
  {newLayout.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div key={item.i}>
        <Card
          summaryNumberOfLines={MAX_SUMMARY_LINES}
          descriptionNumberOfLines={MAX_DESCRIPTION_LINES}
          issue={item.issue}
          isLoading={item.isLoading}
          showAssignee={showAssignee}
          showReporter={showReporter}
        />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</GridLayout>
```

`